# htaccess redirects for one domain of a multi-language Drupal site

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, drupal

I have a multi language Drupal site with default English on
www.domain.com
and a French site at
www.domain.fr
and a French Canadian site at
fr.domain.ca

I have the same URLs on all three sites for similar content, but now I need to redirect 
www.domain.com/content/a-web-page
but not
fr.domain.ca/content/a-web-page or www.domain.fr/content/a-web-page
If a use the following,

```
RewriteRule ^content/a-web-page http://www.domain.com/a-new-web-page [R=301,L]
```

it redirects every language to the new english page.

I have researched more complicated patterns but I am really stuck.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.domain.com
RewriteRule ^content/a-web-page http://www.domain.com/a-new-web-page [R=301,L]
```

You can read more about RewriteCond here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^content/(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L,NC]
```